How to prove $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n f_n=-\frac{1}{2i}\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}\frac{f_z}{\sin(\pi z)}dz$ in the sense of Borel summation?
As the title shows, I would like to prove this identity in the sense of Borel summation,
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n f_n=-\frac{1}{2i}\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}\frac{f_z}{\sin(\pi z)}dz,$$
providing that $f_z$ is the analytic continuation of $f_n,$ and has no poles on the right half plane (including the imaginary axis), $-1<c<0,$ satisfying the vertical line $(c-i\infty,c+i\infty)$ be at the right of all the poles.
I know that in the sense of regular summation, this can be proved by residue theorem: the residue of $f_z/\sin(\pi z)$ at $z=n$ is $(-1)^n f_n/\pi,$ and given the $f_z$ decays fast enough as $z\to\infty,$ say $f_z\to1/|z|^{1+\epsilon},$ we can construct a semicircle with radius $R\to\infty$ on the right half plane connecting with the vertical line $(c-i\infty,c+i\infty),$ contouring all the poles on the right half plane. And there's no contribution to the integral on the semicircle, we can prove the original identity immediately.
But further I numerically find that this identity seems still be true in the sense of Borel summation!

For $f_n=1,$ $\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n=1/2,$ and using Mathmatica, I calculated $-\frac{1}{2i}\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}\frac{1}{\sin(\pi z)}dz=0.5.$
For $f_n=n,$ $\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n n=-1/4,$ using Mathematica, $-\frac{1}{2i}\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}\frac{z}{\sin(\pi z)}dz=-0.25.$
For $f_n=n!,$ $\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n n!=e \Gamma(0,1)\approx0.5963,$ using Mathematica, $-\frac{1}{2i}\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}\frac{\Gamma(z+1)}{\sin(\pi z)}dz\approx0.5963.$

After many tests, I believe this result is true and perhaps underlying some really deep and beautiful structures of analytic functions. I have no idea how to prove it, since now we can no longer argue that the contribution to the contour integral is zero on the hemicircle at $\infty.$
Any help would be appreciated!

Should the upper limit be $c+i \infty$?

Yes, corrected.

The residue is $(-1) ^n f_n/\pi$.

Corrected. Thank you for pointing it out.

You may look up the Lindelöf summation formula mentioned here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Plana_formula

Yeah, that's an interesting variation. But it seems the proof still relies on $f_z=O\left(|z|^{-1-\epsilon}\right).$ I'm not sure if they have considered this formula can be extended in the sense of Borel sum.

The residue calculus argument should work as long as $f_z=O(e^{Ax+B|y|})$ for $z=x+iy$, $A>0$, and $B<\pi$. For a counter-example, take $f_z=e^z\sin(\pi z)$, so there is
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^nf_n=0
$$
but the integral diverges.

Thanks! Is there any references for the condition you pointed out: $f_z=O(e^{Ax+B|y|})$, or can you elaborate more on this?

See §11.4 of the book Ramanujan by G. H. Hardy. I have also written a Chinese account here.

Thank you! It helps.

@HCZhang The non-alternating version (Abel-Plana formula) is proved under similar conditions in the book Asymptotics and Special Functions by F. W. J. Olver.

@TravorLZH I just find that in some cases the condition is not satisfied while the identity is still true, such as $f_z=\Gamma(z+1)$ (same in the question), and even for $f_z=(-1)^z \Gamma(z+1).$ For the latter case, it gives the Borel summation of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}n!,$ which coincides with the result in link. It is amazing. However, the function $(-1)^z \Gamma(z+1)$ obviously doesn't satisfy $O(e^{Ax+B|y|}).$

And besides, in some cases, such as $f_z=\frac{e^z}{z^2},$ (satisfying the condition) the RHS integral works fine and gives a finite value. But the LHS summation is not Borel summable. So I'm also wondering in this case, in what sense the series is summable if the integral value means something.
